# How can I add an onclick event to a newly created button in JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append, createelement

I created a button with id through function .append(). Now I don't know to add any onclick event to it using its id. Here's what I have.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="indiv"></div>
<script>
$('#indiv').append('<button id="btn1">press</button>'); 
$('#btn1').on('click', function(){
  alert('Hi!');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```js
$('#indiv').append('<button id="btn1">press</button>'); 
$('#btn1').on('click', function(){
  alert('Hi!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="indiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Sure, it needs a new one. I was trying with "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js".

Comment: Glad it worked out, if you are happy with the answer please mark as correct answer.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

TRY this

```
$(document).on('click','#btn1',function(){
 alert('Hi!'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would solve it with plain vanilla JS (Since your question covers both Jquery and JS):

```js
function myscript() {
document.write("My printout");
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="indiv">
      <button onclick="myscript()">My Button</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```